# Diving into props while testing React using Enzyme

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

Is there a better solution to dive into props.text in Enzyme?

Component:

```
export function TitleText ({ text, info, required }) {
  return (
    <div className={style.titleText}>
      <div className={style.titleText} style={{ margin: 0 }} required={required}>{text}</div>
      {info ? <InfoIcon className={style.infoIcon} /> : ''}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Test:

```
it('renders text from its props', () => {
  const wrapper = setupTitleText('Test')
  expect(wrapper.find(`.${style.titleText}`).node.props.children[0].props.children).toEqual('Test')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the props using props(). Should at least work on shallow and mounted components.

```
wrapper.props().text
```

However, I would add a data attribute for testing. 
Doing so would

let anyone working on your code would know that this element is being tested

let anyone working on your code would know that this element is being tested

prevent multiple elements being returned when you're looking to test something specific

prevent others breaking your tests if they decide to change the class.

Comment: It returns an error " Error: Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 2 found instead.", because there are 2 divs with style.titleText className.

Comment: Something you could try is adding data attribute for testing like 'data-test-text' and find that, rather than use a class to search, which could return many results when really you are looking to test something specific.

This would also prevent you having to change the tests if you decide to rename the class and prevent someone else breaking it if they change the class. It would also make it clear to anyone else working with you that this element is tested.

Have updated my answer.